# How to get the id of a div tag in code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am having two div tags and in it there are linkbuttons. When I click on any of the linkbutton I need to get the id of div tag in code behind. I have no idea how to do this.
Below is my code of one div tag:

```
<div id='qhse' class="qhse" runat="server"></div>
```

And C# code:

```
public void GetQHSEManual()
{
    DataTable dsMenu = new DataTable();
    gObj.category = "1";
    dsMenu = gObj.GetAllSubCategory();
    for (int i = 0; i < dsMenu.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        LinkButton myLnkBtn = new LinkButton();
        myLnkBtn.ID = "lbtn1" + dsMenu.Rows[i]["Subcategory"].ToString();
        myLnkBtn.CssClass = "linkButton";
        myLnkBtn.Click += new EventHandler(Dynamic_Click);
        myLnkBtn.Text = dsMenu.Rows[i]["Subcategory"].ToString();
        myLnkBtn.Text += "<br>";
        qhse.Controls.Add(myLnkBtn);    
    }     
}
```

Comment: you mean id of parent div of link button?

Comment: If your id is static `qhse` then why cant you simply access it?

Comment: because i have five more div tags.

Comment: eventhough you use 5 divs id's must be unique for each div

Comment: that id is the name  of my category ,but all the subcategory of the category are same. So when we click a link button,ie subcategory,we should be able to know which div is selected.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it with JavaScript. If you have 1 element inside of your div holder this should be done easy. JavaScript lib allows to use parent id when you click on your button inside div. See jQuery for this purpose.

I would suggest you that you separate server side and client side logic well. Think about local storage, sessions and cookies if you need to pass some data to the backend. In your case I would use an AJAX call from the client and implement some logic on the backend.

Answer (score 0):

`$("a:contains('continue')").closest('div').attr('id');`

Here in this code we are finding parent div id of a href having a text value in display as 'continue'.

Comment: assuming the href has a text display as continue. This can be replaced as having a continue button.

Comment: Please add at least one line of explanation to this post. It has been flagged as low quality.